# Hibernate exception "PropertyValueException: not-null property references a > null or transient value". I am stuck and don't know what to do

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hql

[Here you can see the entity-relationship diagram of my database with associations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL0dL.png)

I am developing a Hibernate inventory management program using Apache Derby in NetBeans. The application will ask the user to select from a preinputted Project/Partner from the Partner database and to enter a date (See ERD above). The user could choose whether the items are incoming or outgoing from the inventory. Supposedly this would create an Advicenote entry into the the Advicenote table as such:

[Selection user interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9wbR.png)

Then in the next window the user would be able to actually set Transaction's value which is associated with the Advicenote:

[Next input window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvWfm.png)

Here is the code with the listeners that would implement this:

```
private void deliveryButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    advice.setAdvicedate((Date) this.dateSpinner.getValue());
    advice.setInOrOut((short)1);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Partner.class);
    partner = (Partner) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("partnerName", this.partnerComboBox.getSelectedItem())).uniqueResult();
    System.out.println("partner");
    advice.setPartner(partner);
    session.save(advice);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    delivery.setVisible(true);
}                                              

private void transferButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    advice.setAdvicedate((Date) this.dateSpinner.getValue());
    advice.setInOrOut((short)-1);
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Partner.class);
    partner = (Partner) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("partnerName", this.partnerComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString())).uniqueResult();
    advice.setPartner(partner);
    session.save(advice);
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
    transfer.setVisible(true);
}
```

Here are the XML mapping files of the classes:

**Partner class**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Partner" table="PARTNER" schema="APP">
        <id name="partnerId" type="int">
            <column name="PARTNER_ID"/>
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="partnerName" type="string" column="PARTNER_NAME" length="100"/>
        <set name="advicenotes" table="ADVICENOTE" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key column="PARTNER_ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="classes.Advicenote" />
        </set>
            </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Advicenote class**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 9, 2019, 3:57:52 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="classes.Advicenote" table="ADVICENOTE" schema="APP" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="advicenoteId" type="int" column="ADVICENOTE_ID">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="advicedate" type="date" column="ADVICE_DATE" length="10" />
        <property name="inOrOut" type="java.lang.Short" column="IN_OR_OUT" />
        <many-to-one 
            name="partner" class="classes.Partner"/>  
        <set name="transactions" table="TRANSACTIONS" inverse="false" cascade="all" lazy="true" fetch="select">       
            <key column="ADVICENOTE_ID" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="classes.Transactions"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**However, I get this error:**

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a
>   null or transient value :
>   classes.Advicenote._classes.Partner.advicenotesBackref    at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:111)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.Nullability.checkNullability(Nullability.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.AbstractEntityInsertAction.nullifyTransientReferencesIfNotAlready(AbstractEntityInsertAction.java:115)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:69)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:332)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:196)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:127)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:705)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:700)     at
>   delivery.view.Selection.deliveryButtonActionPerformed(Selection.java:190)
>     at delivery.view.Selection$2.actionPerformed(Selection.java:106)    at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:297)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6632)
>     at
>   java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6397)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5008)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4840)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
>     at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)  at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)   at
>   java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at
>   java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>     at
>   java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)

**I've been trying for ages to solve this with no luck. I would appriacte every help!**

Comment: My guess is your `partner` variable might be null. Could you print it (and its fields) to check if that variable is valid?

Comment: @ayrton this is what I get Hibernate: `select this_.PARTNER_ID as PARTNER_1_4_0_, this_.PARTNER_NAME as PARTNER_2_4_0_ from APP.PARTNER this_ where this_.PARTNER_NAME=?
classes.Partner@5b822d4c`

Comment: @ayrton with .getName added Hibernate:  `select this_.PARTNER_ID as PARTNER_1_4_0_, this_.PARTNER_NAME as PARTNER_2_4_0_ from APP.PARTNER this_ where this_.PARTNER_NAME=? `
**partner**
 `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : classes.Advicenote._classes.Partner.advicenotesBackref` 
So I reciever the Partner entity, but then why can't I persist it or save it with the session?

Comment: Please show the actual variable, not the query. Also, which line exactly throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined a bi-directional mapping but you are only setting one side.

You have to set the `partner` in the `AdviceNote` and also fill in the `advicenotes` Set on the `Partner`:

```
advice.setPartner(partner);
partner.getAdviceNotes().add(advice);
session.save(advice);
transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Obviously! Thank you, you were right! Would you say that in this case I would be better off with unidirectional associations?

Comment: Not necessarilly, it depends on the needs of you app

Comment: @Maciej_Kowalski also what would be the best way to reference this Advicenote entity in the next window where I enter a Transaction entity, because these Transaction entities would belong to the same Advicenote entity as was entered in the previous window? somehow I would need to get the last inputted ID of the Advicenote table or are there any better solutions for these kinds of problems? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Ideally you should create a new post and describe in more detail. KEep in mind though that SO is problem solving not opinion based. Thanks.